# Ruby/Selenium: How to click on a specific item that appears multiple times on a page and doesn't have unique properties

Tags: ruby, angularjs, selenium

Here's the item in question - specifically that little caret: http://screencast.com/t/NMPOM9Ok58q

As you can see there are multiples of those within the same page, they all have the same class etc.

I've tried several different routes and I've not been able to successfully click on that item.

I always want to click on the last of them present on that page (the number of them are dynamic so sometimes it's the 2nd one and sometimes it's the 6th - so referring to it with a specific number doesn't work)

Thanks for the help (my tests are written in ruby, using selenium and testunit)  The page itself is written in html5 using Angular.

Here are some things I've tried and a few variations of these as well.

```
@driver.find_element(:class, "dropdown-toggle")[-1].click
@driver.find_element(:css, "(//*[contains,'a.dropdown-toggle')]").click 
element_present?(:css, "div.dropdown.open > a.dropdown-toggle").click
@driver.find_element(:css, "div.dropdown.open > a.dropdown-toggle").click
@driver.find_elements(:css, "caret")[-1].click
@driver.find_element(:css, "caret:last-of-type").click
@driver.find_element(:css, "div.dropdown.open > a.dropdown-toggle:last-child").click

@driver.find_element(:class, "span1").find_element(:tag_name, "a").click 
^ This one actually is the only one that clicks anything - but it only clicks the first carat.

@links = @driver.find_element(:class, "span1").find_elements(:tag_name, "a")
@links.last.click
^ This one seems promising but produces an 'element not visible' error. Seen here:  http://screencast.com/t/dcN4EZW8UZf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it (thanks for all the input)

```
@driver.find_elements(:css, "div.span1 > div.dropdown > a.dropdown-toggle")[-1].click
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `nth-last-child(2)` property on the green divs, and select the dropdown item from there.

Comment: like this? @driver.find_element(:css, "span1:nth-last-child(2)").click it just times out on me (No such element)

Comment: No. Not the last second 'span1' element. But search for the last second green div. And then select the 'span1' element there.

Comment: What is the class of the green wrapper around the list elements?

Comment: It appears to be divided up into a few:  part of it is 'span1' seen here: http://screencast.com/t/yzSfxQ06rQjr  

But this part seems to be 'span11' http://screencast.com/t/1BxR29Ys6PvU

and the wrapper on the entire thing is ng-scope:  http://screencast.com/t/HTbyQcbnfnTy

Comment: @driver.find_element(:css, "filters-list-item:nth-last-child(2)")  <= this is to find the last second div. Now select the 'span1' from this one.

Comment: This:@driver.find_element(:class, "filters-list-item:nth-last-child(2)").find_elements(:tag_name, "span1").click
   
Gets me a no such element error:  http://screencast.com/t/zMKzkqRjaKJ

Comment: @driver.find_element(:class, "filters-list-item:nth-last-child(2)") what does this return? Can you show its screencast? Also try to get what does @driver.find_element(:class, "filters-list-item:last-child") return.